# DateTime returning wrong tick amount?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to save time in milliseconds and I want the current date to be 10th jan 2009 at 10am.

This in milliseconds is `1231581600442` and I know there are 10,000 ticks per millisecond but DateTime doesn't return the correct time and if I hardcode it there and get the ticks it doesn't return what I had.

My code:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2009, 1, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0);
Debug.Log(player.GetTime() + " - " + dateTime.Ticks);
Debug.Log("DateTime ms: " + dateTime.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
Debug.Log("Player ms in ticks: " + (player.GetTime() * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond));
```

Output:

```
1231581600442 - 633671784000000000
DateTime ms: 63367178400000
Player ms in ticks: 12315816004420000
```

In Java I turned them milliseconds from DateTime into a readable date and it is 
`10 January 3978 10:00:00`

Does anyone know why this is incorrect and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? I would like to be able to copy, paste and run your code.

Comment: How you parse miliseconds to Datetime ? Probably is a problem with format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Java epoch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH) is beginning of 1970 (`1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), but the C# epoch is 0001-01-01.

See Java `Instant` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#EPOCH).

> …the class stores a long representing epoch-seconds and an int representing nanosecond-of-second, which will always be between 0 and 999,999,999. The epoch-seconds are measured from the standard Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z where instants after the epoch have positive values, and earlier instants have negative values.

See the `DateTime` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks, and a particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 A.D. (C.E.) in the GregorianCalendar calendar (excluding ticks that would be added by leap seconds).

You'll need to account for this:

```
DateTime dateTime  = new DateTime(2009, 1, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime javaEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

long msSinceJavaEpoch = (dateTime.Ticks - javaEpoch.Ticks)/TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

// Use msSinceJavaEpoch to convert to Java time.
```

Comment: Was writing basically the same. +1

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!